# Localized xib files is not being used

Tags: iphone, ios

I created bunch of localized xib files -- Chinese, Japanese, etc. But when I switch my iphone language, the localized xibs are not being used and the labels remain Eng. However the strings are being picked up correctly.

Anybody have any ideas where I should troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to do a Clean build on the project, then delete the app on the device, then rebuild/reinstall. Just doing a Clean build wasn't enough, but deleting the app and reinstalling did the trick.